# Finding the total differential for the matrix function $F(A) = A^T A - \mathbb{1}_{n \times n}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I am having difficulties understanding how to find the total differential for the function

$F: Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow S_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$

where $S_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all symmetric matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ and

$F(A) = A^T A - \mathbb{1}_{n \times n}$.

I found that it should be given by

$DF_{X}(\xi) = \xi^T X - X^T \xi$ (at the point $X$).

I am pretty sure that is pretty straight forward, but I am unable to find a way to this results.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Compute $F(A + H) -F(A) = (A + H)^T(A + H) - A^TA = A^TH + H^T A + H^TH$, and drop the quadratic term.

Comment: @DanielFischer +1 but you should post this as answer so the system doesn't treat this question as unanswered anymore. (Or #mathqu could do so)

Comment: I marked the answer below, I hope that is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f\colon  Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow  Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\times  Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}),\ A\mapsto (A,A)$$ and $$g\colon  Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\times  Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow  Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}),\ (A,B)\mapsto A^tB$$
then it's clear that $f$ is linear and $g$ is bilinear and $F=g\circ f+Constant$ so

$$DF(A)H=Dg(f(A))Df(A)H=Dg(f(A))(H,H)=A^tH+HB$$

Comment: Back at you! ;-)